# Lookup table or Check constraint to classify a game

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
create table dbo.Games ( 
  Id int not null
    constraint PK_Games_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)
```

I need to classify the Game by DifficultyLevel (3 Levels) and by TimeToCompleteLevel (4 Levels).

Should I use lookup table for these levels and then use a FK in Games table?

Or should I add two columns to the table with a constraint?

And if I add two columns what should I save? A number or the level text itself?

NOTE: I will to search the Games by both levels.

Comment: What DB application?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use an ENUM. The value will be stored/indexed as an integer but will appear to be text when performing inserts, updates, and selects.

(This option may not apply to SQL-Server.)